# EPS board with compressive strength declared 600kPa, can it withstand 6kg/cm2 without deforming

Tags: structural-engineering

600 kPa is declared for boards of 600x1200 and the same for 1200x2400 (mm)
Does that mean that they have calculated this 600kPa for the material as such or is it a given per m²?

convert 600000 N/m² to kg/m² ≈ 61,092 kg/m² /10.000 = 6.1092 kg/cm²

So if I exert a force of 6kg on a square centimeter, I will not have deformation? if I go beyond 6.11kg I will break it?